# Scotty: connection pool as monad reader

Tags: haskell, scotty, haskell-wai

There are trillions of monad tutorial including the reader and it seems all clear when you read about it. But when you actually need to write, it becomes a different matter.

I'v never used the Reader, just never got to it in practice. So I don't know how to go about it although I read about it.

I need to implement a simple database connection pool in Scotty so every action can use the pool. The pool must be "global" and accessible by all action functions. I read that the way to do it is the Reader monad. If there are any other ways please let me know.

Can you please help me and show how to do this with the Reader correctly?
I'll probably learn faster if I see how it is done with my own examples.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module DB where

import Data.Pool
import Database.MongoDB

-- Get data from config
ip = "127.0.0.1"
db = "index"

--Create the connection pool
pool :: IO (Pool Pipe)
pool = createPool (runIOE $ connect $ host ip) close 1 300 5

-- Run a database action with connection pool
run :: Action IO a -> IO (Either Failure a)
run act = flip withResource (\x -> access x master db act) =<< pool
```

So the above is simple. and I want to use the 'run' function in every Scotty action to access the database connection pool. Now, the question is how to wrap it in the Reader monad to make it accessible by all functions? I understand that the 'pool' variable must be 'like global' to all the Scotty action functions.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I am updating the question with the full code snippet. Where I pass the 'pool' variable down the function chain. If someone can show how to change it to utilize the monad Reader please.
I don't understand how to do it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Network.HTTP.Types
import Web.Scotty
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as LT
import Data.Text.Lazy.Internal
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)
import Data.Aeson (object, (.=), encode)
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Static
import Data.Pool
import Database.MongoDB
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO,lift)

main = do
  -- Create connection pool to be accessible by all action functions
  pool <- createPool (runIOE $ connect $ host "127.0.0.1") close 1 300 5
  scotty 3000 (basal pool)

basal :: Pool Pipe -> ScottyM ()
basal pool = do
  middleware $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "static")
  get "/json" (showJson pool)

showJson :: Pool Pipe -> ActionM ()
showJson pool = do
  let run act = withResource pool (\pipe -> access pipe master "index" act) 
  d <- lift $ run $ fetch (select [] "tables")
  let r = either (const []) id d
  text $ LT.pack $ show r
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to do it the way it was suggested below but it does not work.
If anyone has any ideas, please. The list of compile errors is so long that I don't even know where to begin ....

```
main = do
  pool <- createPool (runIOE $ connect $ host "127.0.0.1") close 1 300 5
  scotty 3000 $ runReaderT basal pool

basal :: ScottyT LT.Text (ReaderT (Pool Pipe) IO) ()
basal = do
  middleware $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "static")
  get "/json" $ showJson

showJson :: ActionT LT.Text (ReaderT (Pool Pipe) IO) ()
showJson = do
  p <- lift ask
  let rdb a = withResource p (\pipe -> access pipe master "index" a)
  j <- liftIO $ rdb $ fetch (select [] "tables")
  text $ LT.pack $ show j
```

**UPDATE 3**

Thanks to *cdk* for giving the idea and thanks to *Ivan Meredith* for giving the scottyT suggestion. This question also helped: [How do I add the Reader monad to Scotty's monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070235/how-do-i-add-the-reader-monad-to-scottys-monad)
This is the version that compiles. I hope it helps someone and saves some time.

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as T
import           Data.Text.Lazy (Text)
import           Control.Monad.Reader
import           Web.Scotty.Trans
import           Data.Pool
import           Database.MongoDB

type ScottyD = ScottyT Text (ReaderT (Pool Pipe) IO)
type ActionD = ActionT Text (ReaderT (Pool Pipe) IO)

-- Get data from config
ip = "127.0.0.1"
db = "basal"

main = do
  pool <- createPool (runIOE $ connect $ host ip) close 1 300 5
  let read = \r -> runReaderT r pool
  scottyT 3000 read read basal

-- Application, meaddleware and routes
basal ::  ScottyD ()
basal = do
  get "/" shoot

-- Route action handlers
shoot ::  ActionD ()
shoot = do
  r <- rundb $ fetch $ select [] "computers"
  html $ T.pack $ show r

-- Database access shortcut
rundb :: Action IO a -> ActionD (Either Failure a)
rundb a = do
  pool <- lift ask
  liftIO $ withResource pool (\pipe -> access pipe master db a)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been trying to figure out this exact problem myself. Thanks to hints on this SO question, and other research I've come up with the following which works for me. The key bit you were missing was to use `scottyT`

No doubt there is a prettier way to write runDB but I don't have much experience in Haskell, so please post it if you can do better.

```
type MCScottyM = ScottyT TL.Text (ReaderT (Pool Pipe) IO)
type MCActionM = ActionT TL.Text (ReaderT (Pool Pipe) IO)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  pool <- createPool (runIOE $ connect $ host "127.0.0.1") close 1 300 5  
  scottyT 3000 (f pool) (f pool) $ app
    where
      f = \p -> \r -> runReaderT r p

app :: MCScottyM ()
app = do
  middleware $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "public")
  get "/" $ do 
    p <- runDB dataSources 
    html $ TL.pack $ show p 

runDB :: Action IO a -> MCActionM (Either Failure a) 
runDB a = (lift ask) >>= (\p ->  liftIO $ withResource p (\pipe -> access pipe master "botland" a))

dataSources :: Action IO [Document]
dataSources = rest =<< find (select [] "datasources")
```

### Update

I guess this a bit more pretty.

```
runDB :: Action IO a -> MCActionM (Either Failure a) 
runDB a = do
  p <- lift ask
  liftIO $ withResource p db
    where
       db pipe = access pipe master "botland" a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the scottyT suggestion. I pretty much got to this point minus the scottyT. I tried it with scottyT but it still does not work. I think the problrm is in the `get` function which takes and returns the old ActionM and ScottyM respectevely - not the new data types augmented with the reader. I am not worried about the `runDB` function at the moment, it is the easier part. All I need is to crack the reader problem and pass the pool down to the handler. So far nothing works. Simple emulation of "global" variable turned into a global problem for me for weeks...

Comment: Oh.. well... I think I got it right after I typed the comment to your post. I should'v used `get` function from the `Web.Scotty.Trans`, not from the `Web.Scotty`.

Comment: I updated the question with the working version. I still don't quite understand the `scottyT` parameters and why we apply `runReaderT` twice? If you can explain it I'd really appreciate it. Thanks once again.

Comment: You have to do it once for ScottyT and once for ActionT - in theory you can inject different environments for both I think.

Comment: Note that this has changed in Scotty 0.10. You now only use one `runReaderT`, the one run in `ActionT`.

Answer (score 2):

As you've alluded, the way to make it accessable is to wrap your computations in the `Reader` monad or more likely the `ReaderT` transformer. So your `run` function (changed slightly)

```
run :: Pool Pipe -> Action IO a -> IO (Either Failure a)
run pool act =
    flip withResource (\x -> access x master db act) =<< pool
```

becomes

```
run :: Action IO a -> ReaderT (Pool Pipe) IO (Either Failure a)
run act = do
    pool <- ask
    withResource pool (\x -> access x master db act)
```

Computations inside a `ReaderT r m a` environment can access the `r` using `ask` and `ReaderT` seemingly conjures it out of thin air! In reality, the `ReaderT` monad is just plumbing the `Env` throughout the computation without you having to worry about it.

To run a `ReaderT` action, you use `runReaderT :: ReaderT r m a -> r -> m a`. So you call `runReaderT` on your top level `scotty` function to provide the `Pool` and `runReaderT` will unwrap the `ReaderT` environment and return you a value in the base monad.

For example, to evaluate your `run` function

```
-- remember: run act :: ReaderT (Pool Pipe) IO (Either Failure a)
runReaderT (run act) pool
```

but you wouldn't want to use `runReaderT` on `run`, as it is probably part of a larger computation that should also share the `ReaderT` environment. Try to avoid using `runReaderT` on "leaf" computations, you should generally call it as high up in the program logic as possible.

**EDIT**: The difference between `Reader` and `ReaderT` is that `Reader` is a monad while `ReaderT` is a monad *transformer*. That is, `ReaderT` adds the `Reader` behaviour to another monad (or monad transformer stack). If you're not familiar with monad transformers I'd recommend [real world haskell - transformers](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html).

You have `showJson pool ~ ActionM ()` and you want to add a `Reader` environment with access to a `Pool Pipe`. In this case, you actually need `ActionT` and `ScottyT` transformers rather than `ReaderT` in order to work with functions from the `scotty` package.

Note that `ActionM` is defined `type ActionM = ActionT Text IO`, similarly for `ScottyM`.

I don't have all the necessary libraries installed, so this might not typecheck, but it should give you the right idea.

```
basal :: ScottyT Text (ReaderT (Pool Pipe) IO) ()
basal = do
    middleware $ staticPolicy (...)
    get "/json" showJson

showJson :: ActionT Text (ReaderT (Pool Pipe) IO) ()
showJson = do
    pool <- lift ask
    let run act = withResource pool (\p -> access p master "index act)
    d <- liftIO $ run $ fetch $ select [] "tables"
    text . TL.pack $ either (const "") show d
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I am sorry but I don't understand it. I tried but it just does not click in my mind. I made the run function as you suggested but it is no point copy and paste if I can not grasp it. Some examples say I need to use the transformer and some say I just need the Reader. What is the difference? I will update my question showing the whole code snippet where I pass the 'pipe' variable down the function chain. Can you please show me how to do it. I spend the weekend trying to understand it. I know it must be simple but it just does not click.

Comment: Thanks for your update but unfortunately it does not work. I tried leaving the type signatures out hoping that GHC will deduct it and gives me some clues but no luck.