# How to get ReaderT to work with another monad transformer?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I would like to embed `ReaderT` into another monad transformer. How do I do this? The example below uses [`Scotty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.9.0/docs/Web-Scotty-Trans.html) but I think it would be the same with any other monad.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Web.Scotty
import Web.Scotty.Trans

import Data.Text.Lazy
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans

data Config = Config Text

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let config = Config "Hello World"
    -- how to I make this line work?
    scottyT 3000 id id routes

routes :: ScottyT Text (ReaderT Config IO) ()
routes = do
    get "/" info

info :: ActionT Text (ReaderT Config IO) ()
info = do
    -- this part seems like it works!
    Config message <- lift ask
    text $ "Info: " `append` message
```

This errors on the line `scottyT 3000 id id routes`, because `scottyT` expects a `ScottyT Text IO ()`. How do I make this work? Here are the current errors:

```
Server.hs: line 24, column 24:
  Couldn't match type `ReaderT Config IO' with `IO'
    Expected type: ScottyT Text IO ()
      Actual type: ScottyT Text (ReaderT Config IO) ()
```

Comment: Well, this works but I'm not sure it's right: `flip runReaderT config $ scottyT 3000 id (flip runReaderT config) routes`.  I don't think it's correct considering `runReaderT` is needed twice, but I don't know enough about scotty to know why the `scottyT` function requires that argument

Comment: Could you just change the order of the "Transformes stack" i.e. `ReaderT Config (ScottyT Text IO) ()`?

Comment: Based off of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23190718/839246) answer, you can do `scottyT 3000 (flip runReaderT) (flip runReaderT) routes, and that seems to be the way other people have done it.

Comment: @chaosmasttter Unfortunately, no.  The `get` function has the type `(ScottyError e, MonadIO m) => RoutePattern -> ActionT e m () -> ScottyT e m ()`, instead of the more general `(ScottyError e, MonadIO m, MonadAction a, MonadScotty s) => RoutePattern -> a e m () -> s e m ()`

Comment: @chaosmasttter I don't want to. I want to be able to use `Scotty` stuff without lifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the arguments you've supplied as `id` to be ones that have the type `forall a. m a -> n a` and `m Response -> IO Response` respectively.  Why?  I don't know, but the example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23190718/839246) shows someone running it similar to

```
main = do
    let config = Config "Hello, world"
        runner = flip runReaderT config
    scottyT 3000 runner runner routes
```

I've tested it, and it at least works.  Whether or not this is best practices is unknown to me.  If someone has a better method, feel free to post it.

Comment: How would it look with a more understandable monad? It looks like Scotty added some magic to enable this, but what if they hadn't? would it still be possible?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess What I've normally seen is that you'd have something like `scottyT :: (ScottyError e, MonadIO m) => Port -> ScottyT e m () -> m ()`, then you could have `flip runReaderT config $ scottyT 3000 routes` instead by only running the `ScottyT` layer. It seems that scotty requires some more advanced behavior for executing the actions, I find it hard to believe that they'd need these complex extra parameters just from poor API design. Personally, I would prefer being able to run the `ReaderT` monad first, leaving a `ScottyM` monad as my base to just run with `scotty`, but that's just me

Comment: For Scotty ≥ 0.10, `scottyT` no longer takes the “Run monad 'm' into monad 'n', called once at 'ScottyT' level” parameter, so the last line should be `scottyT 3000 runner routes`.