# Scotty and the Reader Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, scotty, reader-monad

I'm trying to bring the Reader monad in my Scotty application, as a means of having a unified root path for URL expansion internally. I can't seem to wrap my head around how Scotty handles monad transformation - normally, I would just see something like `runTransformerT ...`, but `scottyT` has a lot of internal plumbing to do, so the result is really just a `MonadIO n => n ()` (forced to `IO ()` if used in the `main` function, like I am here).

Here is my code so far:

```
main :: IO ()
main = scottyT 3000
  (\x -> runReaderT x "foo.com")
  id $ do
    root <- lift ask
    get "/" $
      text root
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
src/Main.hs:16:21:
    Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘ReaderT r0 IO’
    Expected type: ReaderT r0 IO a
      Actual type: IO a
    In the first argument of ‘runReaderT’, namely ‘x’
    In the expression: runReaderT x "foo.com"
```

How do I use this magic?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065765/how-to-get-readert-to-work-with-another-monad-transformer/26065994#26065994) solve your problem?

Comment: For some reason "Scotty and the Reader Monad" sounds like a book title...

Comment: bheklilr: Yes, it did! Thank you!

Comment: @AthanClark Then I'll mark it as a duplicate.  This will hopefully help someone with your same problem find the solution faster in the future.