# How do I use a persistent State monad with Spock?

Tags: rest, haskell, monads, state-monad, haskell-spock

I'm just starting out with haskell and I'm having issues with a basic "echo" REST server.

Spock looked like a nice starting place for a REST server, and I though I got the basics of the State monad, but I'm having issues understanding how to put a `runState` around the spock code.

Here's the code I've got so far.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Data.Monoid
import Web.Spock.Safe
import qualified Control.Monad.State as S

storeData :: String -> S.State String String
storeData val = do S.put val
                   return val

getData :: S.State String String
getData = do val <- S.get
             return val

main :: IO ()
main =
    runSpock 11350 $ spockT id $
    do get "store" $
           text "Would be a call to getData"
```

Comment: The key to this puzzle is the first argument of `spockT`, which you will need to provide for `m ~ State String`. However, you will run into the exact same issue as explained [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27496393/477476): the `State String` will not be automagically persisted between handler invocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so here's a version of the [`restartableStateT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27496393/477476) hack for your example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
module Main where

import Data.Monoid
import Data.String (fromString)
import Web.Spock.Safe
import qualified Control.Monad.State as S
import Data.IORef

storeData :: (Monad m) => String -> S.StateT String m String
storeData val = do S.put val
                   return val

getData :: (Monad m) => S.StateT String m String
getData = do val <- S.get
             return val

newtype RunStateT s m = RunStateT{ runStateT :: forall a. S.StateT s m a -> m a }

restartableStateT :: s -> IO (RunStateT s IO)
restartableStateT s0 = do
    r <- newIORef s0
    return $ RunStateT $ \act -> do
        s <- readIORef r
        (x, s') <- S.runStateT act s
        atomicModifyIORef' r $ const (s', x)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    runner <- restartableStateT "initial state"
    runSpock 11350 $ spockT (runStateT runner) $ do
        get "store" $ do
            cmd <- param "value"
            case cmd of
                Nothing -> do
                    old <- S.lift getData
                    text $ fromString old
                Just new -> do
                    S.lift $ storeData new
                    text "Stored."
```

Like the other answer, this one creates a single global `IORef` to store "the state". The `runner` passed to `spockT` is then able to run any `StateT String IO` computation by getting the state from this `IORef`, running the computation, and putting the resulting state back into the `IORef`.

I would like to reiterate from the other answer that this is not necessarily a good idea, because it has no story for concurrency. I guess that could be papered over by using STM for example, but... I think you should just use a database for this kind of thing.

Comment: Normally I would just use a DB, but this was just to try out. Thank you for the information, now I've got a bunch of things to learn.