# How to add a monad transformer into a Spock app?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, haskell-spock

I have a basic hello world Spock app from following the [tutorial](https://www.spock.li/tutorials/getting-started), but now I want to add my own monad transformer, `FooT`, into the Spock transformer stack somehow.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952792/how-do-i-use-a-persistent-state-monad-with-spock), but it looks like `spockT` isn't really used in the latest version of spock. Looks like now there is a `spock` function that takes a `SpockCfg` and a `SpockM`, but I don't see anything that takes an `m` argument where I can specify my monad transformer. Is it still possible to insert a `FooT`, `StateT`, or any other monad transformer into the spock transformer stack somehow? What am I misunderstanding? Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Spock are you using? Looking at the [latest version](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-0.13.0.0/docs/Web-Spock.html) it seems that `SpockM` is just a type alias for `SpockCtxT`, which is a monad transformer, and the alias uses [`WebStateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-0.13.0.0/docs/Web-Spock.html#t:WebStateM) inside. Perhaps adding `Statet` somewhere within this stack might work.

Comment: I'm on version 0.13.0.0. Yeah, it looks like the transformer stack they use is SpockCtxT -> WebStateT -> ResourceT -> IO, but with no apparent way to insert `m` anywhere. My best guess at the moment, is that they expect you to revert back to the `spockT` function in order to use a custom monad, but then you lose all the nice features of `spock`, `SpockCfg` and `SpockM`.