# Scotty monad transformer for per-handler Reader

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, scotty

In the question [Web, Scotty: connection pool as monad reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703289/web-scotty-connection-pool-as-monad-reader) it is shown how to use `ScottyT` to embed a `Reader` monad in the stack to access a static configuration (in that case, a connection pool).

I have a similar question, but simpler – or at least I thought so…

I want to add a `Reader` to a single handler (i.e. a `ActionT`), not the whole app.

I started modifying the program from the question above, but I cannot figure out how to turn an `ActionT Text (ReaderT String IO)` into the `ActionT Text IO` the handler needs to be. After fumbling around and trying to use typed holes hoping to see how to construct this I have to give up for now and ask for help. I really feel this should be simple, but cannot figure out how to do this.

Here's the program, with the lines where I'm stuck highlighted:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import           Data.Text.Lazy (Text)
import           Control.Monad.Reader
import           Web.Scotty.Trans

type ActionD = ActionT Text (ReaderT String IO)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  scottyT 3000 id id app

-- Application
app ::  ScottyT Text IO ()
app = do
  get "/foo" $ do
    h <- handler              -- ?
    runReaderT h "foo"        -- ?
--get "/bar" $ do
--  h <- handler
--  runReaderT h "bar"

-- Route action handler
handler ::  ActionD ()
handler = do
  config <- lift ask
  html $ T.pack $ show config
```

Comment: Interesting. I have no idea about how to do this in a generic way -- it is possible that this requires to tear apart the `ActionT` and rebuild it. However, that type is opaque, so we can not...

Comment: Oh. Hmm. Maybe you're right. I could of course explicitly pass the config to the handlers and from there on to the functions they call, but I had this vague idea that whenever one does that, `Reader` can be used instead.

Comment: The issue seems to be turning `t1 (t2 m) a` into `t1 m a`, where `t1,t2` are monad transformers. Or, more generically, `t m1 a` into `t m2 a` where `m1,m2` are monads. This looks as a functor-ish requirement on `t`: given `f :: forall b. m1 b -> m2 b` you would like to have `fmapT f :: t m1 a -> t m2 a`. Maybe not all transformers would allow `fmapT` but this could be a typeclass on its own. Or maybe there's some way to craft it with standard tools I am not seeing right now :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run each action in a separate reader, you don't need the more complex `Scotty.Trans` interface at all. You can just build you monad stack the other way around, with `ReaderT` on top.

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import           Control.Monad.Reader
import           Web.Scotty

type ActionD = ReaderT String ActionM

main :: IO ()
main = do
  scotty 3000 app

-- Application
app ::  ScottyM ()
app = do
  get "/foo" $ do
    runReaderT handler "foo"

-- Route action handler
handler ::  ActionD ()
handler = do
  config <- ask
  lift $ html $ T.pack $ show config
```

Comment: Right. I guess that's the way to do it. I would prefer to avoid `lift`s for `ActionM` operations, since there will be far, far fewer `Reader` operations, but perhaps that's unavoidable.